# Visual Basic app not seeing .CMD file in same install folder?

Tags: vb.net, windows, batch-file, cmd

I've made an application that gets installed/deployed to /Program Files/STUDYvault/ called "STUDYvault Client.exe" and in the app, a button triggers/calls a .cmd that's in the same directory, called 'Scripts System.cmd'

```
    Private Sub SynchroniseToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MenuBackup.Click
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("SCRIPTS SYSTEM.cmd")
End Sub
```

The .CMD just runs basic xcopy commands for backups. When the software is executed manually, it sees the .cmd within the same directory, however, when it is run by the system (eg startup, either by registry key or via shortcut in the startup folder) (I tried both Inno Setup AND NSIS), it crashes with an Unhandled Exception, 'Cannot find the file specified'. I'm thinking the OS is executing the .exe but running it in say /Windows or /System32 or something. It doesn't seem to be an issue with the visual studio app (it runs when executed manually, and finds the .cmd no matter what the directory) or the installer (it's basically just extracting to /Program Files and putting a link in the startup part of the registry)

My friend and I thought up a workaround, although it's quite nefarious. One could force the user to install the software to *C:/Program Files/STUDYvault* and have it **unchangeable**, and then in the app have it point to *C:/Program Files/STUDYvault/Scripts System.cmd* instead of just "SCRIPTS SYSTEM.cmd" - could this work also?

I'm sure I'm just missing something stupidly small, because the application fires the following code fine when installed:

```
    Private Sub HivemindTechToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles HivemindTechToolStripMenuItem.Click
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://my-website.com.au")
End Sub
```

**EDIT:**
Alright, I've developed a work-around for anyone having this issue. It seems to be rights-related or where the system is executing it from; so it's calling on the .CMD from wherever that is (most likely not its install directory) - so in-app I've had it call on:

```
    Private Sub SynchroniseToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MenuBackup.Click
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\STUDYvault\\SCRIPTSYSTEM.cmd")
End Sub
```

Which is the install directory, and then in the installer (Inno Setup) I've used the following for defining the install directory under [setup]:

```
DefaultDirName={sd}\Program Files (x86)\STUDYvault
DefaultGroupName={#MyAppName}
DisableProgramGroupPage=yes
DisableDirPage=yes
```

Here, DefaultDirName=SD\DIRECTORY defines that it will be force-installed to Program Files (x86) (Fine for 64-bit Windows users, 32-bit users will have to deal with a second Program Files folder but x64 is the most common install in this day and age anyway so we won't have an issue there); DisableDirPage=yes hides the install page that asks the user where they want to install it - most users will leave it as-is but for the more curious user who may want to change it, this WILL break the install, seeing as it's calling on /Program Files (x86)/STUDYvault in-app.

It's a relatively dirty fix, and I feel like Dr. Evil here, but ...it works. Hopefully this will help anyone having a similar issue in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
    Process.Start(Application.StartupPath & "\SCRIPTSYSTEM.cmd")
```

Comment: I used that for the button, and it worked beautifully. I had a feeling it would be something small. My method of locking-in an install directory worked but it felt somewhat restrictive, so I've implemented this into the roll-out version. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can get location of the executable file by using [`Environment.CurrentDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.currentdirectory%28v=vs.110%29). Using this property we can make the code works regardless of executable folder location (as long as cmd file exist in the same folder, of course). So this maybe a more proper way to get the job done :

```
Dim batchFilePath As String = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, _
                                            "SCRIPTS SYSTEM.cmd")
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(batchFilePath)
```

You may want to improve it further by adding logic to check if cmd file actually exist in the location pointed by `batchFilePath` (you can use [`System.IO.File.Exists()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to do that).

Comment: I implemented Saeed's suggestion above, however I tested your solution and that worked wonderfully too. I'm just going for simple solutions here however later down the track when later versions roll out, I will probably replace it with the solution you provided. Thanks!